# svn to merge trunk into branch

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I have a SVN tree is like below

```
trunk ——-*-----*-----------------------------*--------------------*-------------------->
         r340   \                            r344                 r405
                 \                           (bug fix)            (new stable trunk)
                  \
                   *--------*----------*---------------------->branches/myBranch
                   r341     r342       r343
                  (branch)  (bug fix)  (bug fix)
```

I know I can merge my branch changes into the trunk via the following commands:

```
$svn checkout http://svn.example.com/trunk
   Checked out revision r405.
$cd trunk
$svn merge -r 341:405 http://svn.example.com/branches/myBranch
$svn commit -m "merge myBranch changes r341:405 into the trunk"
```

How to merge trunk r405 into my branch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- For merging *any tree into any* you have to use in Subversion the same workflow

  - checkout $TARGET
  - (cd $TARGET)
  - merge $SOURCE
- In case of using SVN 1.6+, not ancient 1.4, which doesn't have mergeinfo (you use supported versions of Subversion, isn't it?), you can skip merge-range in case of ordinary sync-merge you can skip merge-range - all unmerged revisions will be merged anyway

Comment: I am using SVN 1.8.9.
You meant i can skip merge-range, so is my following procedure correct?
$svn checkout http://svn.example.com/branches/myBranch;
$cd myBranch;
$svn merge http://svn.example.com/trunk;

Comment: @srjohnhuang - 1. Yes 2. Shortest merge for you will be `svn merge ^/trunk`

Comment: thanks! by the way, by skipping the merge-range, what is the default merge range will be??

Comment: @srjohnhuang - all possible revisions, you can see it with `svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible $SOURCE $TARGET`